# Mac Terminal to run a bash script that starts a swift program & restarts every hour

Tags: swift, bash, macos, terminal

I am looking for some support on creating some way of running a swift command in terminal to run a program and then stop it after 1 hour then restart.

Example of manual process:

1. Open Termain.
2. `cd my app`
3. `swift run my program --with-parameters`
4. ctrl+c (after 1 hours)
5. Restart with step 3

I am sure there must be some way using a bash script maybe to start the program by command, kill it after 60min and restart it with a continuous loop like that.

Thanks :-)

Comment: Welcome! You can start with `man cron`, `man 5 crontab`, `man killall` (or `man kill` & `echo $!`). If it wont work for you, update the question with your script and a description what doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a cron job to do this. Basically, you'll have a bash script, say it's located at `/Users/ben/scripts/run_my_program.sh` that will, at every hour:

1. Terminate the current running process (kill pid)
2. Execute the `swift run my program --with-parameters` and spit out the process ID

Answer (score 0):

you can get the PID of the swift process you launch with `echo $!`, and then use `sleep 1h` to sleep for 1 hour and then kill the process with `kill -9` and the PID you got in the first step.